# Help! How can I deploy to Mainnet

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

Spending months of studying and testing my code. It is now time to deploy to the mainnet. But unfortunately my Ethereum node takes ages to sync :(

May I know if there is any alternative way for me to upload my contract? I need to get it uploaded by tonight.

Comment: Have you checked out infura?

Comment: Metamask+remix will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick workaround as you're pressed by time check.

The figure below depicts how to use remix(remix.ethereum.org) and metamask to deploy a contract without the need to sync a node.

[image]

NB : if you have already an existing account you can import it to metamask

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot!!!! I was testing out Remix but was only able to deploy into testnet. I think I must run remix and metamask in the same browser then only can deploy onto the mainnet!

Comment: happy to help if it answers your question, don't forget to accept it.